# Android selectableItemBackground ripple color

Tags: android

I'm using `CardView` with an only image inside. To enable `onClick` animation I'm using this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">
```

The problem in that that if the image is dark then ripple effect does not visible upon it. How to solve that problem? Somehow detects is image dark or light and then change programmatically ripple color